# How does the JNDI InitialContext null constructor behave ?

Tags: java, jndi

I saw a stackoverflow answer to a question on JNDI.

The answer showed a few lines of code using InitialContext to retrieve a DataSource.

However, the instance of InitialContext was not created with any properties to use any sort of service such as LDAP or the file system.

Where does the entry go when you bind it to an InitialContext with the null constructor ?

Will the entry only visible within the application ?

Will it not persist when you shutdown the application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where does the entry go when you bind it to an InitialContext with the null constructor?

If there is a resource file named `/jndi.properties` it uses whatever environment is defined in there. Servlet containers typically use this to define an extra object factory for the `java:` namespace.

> Will the entry only [be] visible within the application?

Yes.

> Will it not persist when you shutdown the application?

It will not persist unless the container implements that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you tell me where I could read about how it uses /jndi.properties by default ? Thank you again. :)

Comment: It's in the JNDI documentation.